# Отсечь спецзнак в хинди-букве внутри div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужна помощь в отсечении спецзнака в хинди-букве.
Отдельной буквы без спецзнака не нашел.

По правилам хинди, при наборе такой буквы она сливается с предыдущей буквой и спецзнак автоматом пропадает, но мне ее нужно разместить отдельной буквой в div - спецзнак портит восприятие и мешается попросту.

Картинкой сделать не подойдет, нужен текст.

Вот как выглядят буквы, спецзнак - это пунктирный круг:

ा
ी
ि
ो
ौ

Comment: сложная задачка, похоже что тут только фильтрация по средствам регулярки, на определенные символы... но эт очень дорого если у вас прям объемный поток текста. Лучше попросить что б вам с бэка приходил чистый текст без указанного символа.

Comment: этот спецсимвол в отдельном виде вроде не существует.
есть фоны другие - где на одной странице почему-то нет спецзнака, а когда внутрь заходищь - появляется. [google fonts ](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=devanagari&preview.text=%E0%A5%80%20&preview.text_type=custom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт - помог шрифт отсюда
https://en.maisfontes.com/devanagari-mt-2.font

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/802120)

Comment: Отличное замечание, вот только оно здесь в данном случае неуместно, поскольку сказать здесь больше нечего, кроме как привести название шрифта. Самое название шрифта находится в ссылке - она-то сама никуда не денется.